# How to typehint custom and overridden Managers in an Abstract Class using django-stubs?

Tags: python, django, type-hinting, mypy, django-stubs

we are trying to add typehints to our django (3.2) project. We are using django-stubs (1.12.0).

We have an `AbstractBaseModel` with a custom `BaseManager` that we use for almost every other model. In some cases we also extend the custom Manager.

Example:

```
class BaseManager(models.Manager):
    # ...

class AbstractBaseModel(models.Model):
    # ...
    objects = BaseManager()
    # ...

class MyManager(BaseManager):
    # ...

class MyModel(AbstractBaseModel):
    # ...
    objects = MyManager()
    # ...
```

When I run this through mypy (0.982), I get this error on the `objects` assignment of `MyModel`:

```
Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "MyManager[MyModel]", 
base class "AbstractBaseModel" defined the type as 
"AbstractBaseModel_BaseManager2[AbstractBaseModel]")
```

How would I add typehints to this?
Thank you!

Comment: I get a different error, when I run the above code through `mypy` with the same versions you mentioned. For the inheritance `class BaseManager(models.Manager)` I get the following: `error: Missing type parameters for generic type "Manager"  [type-arg]`

Answer (score 2):

As I said in my comment above, I could not reproduce that same error you described. It seems that in the `django-stubs` the [`BaseManager`](https://github.com/typeddjango/django-stubs/blob/django-stubs%401.12.0/django-stubs/db/models/manager.pyi#L26) is defined as a covariant generic type over any `Model` (sub-)class.

So I would annotate the code you provided as follows:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from typing import TypeVar

from django.db import models


M = TypeVar("M", bound=models.Model, covariant=True)


class BaseManager(models.Manager[M]):
    pass


class AbstractBaseModel(models.Model):
    objects: BaseManager[AbstractBaseModel] = BaseManager()


class MyManager(BaseManager[M]):
    pass


class MyModel(AbstractBaseModel):
    objects: BaseManager[MyModel] = MyManager()
```

This passes `mypy --strict` without issues.

Versions used:

```
Python==3.10.7
Django==3.2
django-stubs==1.12.0
django-stubs-ext==0.5.0
mypy==0.982
mypy-extensions==0.4.3
```